# simple pagination jquery always have 10 rows

Tags: jquery, pagination

```
var items;
var perPage = 10;

// now setup pagination
var $pagination = $("#searchresult");
$pagination.pagination({
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    cssStyle: "light-theme",
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
        // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

        items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
            .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();

    }
});
function updateItems() {
    items = $(".paginate");

    // we'll update the number of items that the pagination element expects
    // using a method from the simplePagination documentation: updateItems
    $pagination.pagination("updateItems", items.length);
    // next we'll re-select the page so the onPageClick function we already
    // programmed will handle hiding and showing the correct content for us

    // note that the page we were on before may no longer exist (i.e. if
    // elements were removed and that page is no longer required), so we
    // will make sure to select an existing page
    var page = Math.min(
        $pagination.pagination("getCurrentPage"),
        $pagination.pagination("getPagesCount")
    );

    $pagination.pagination("selectPage", page);

    var tablerow = $("#searchresult").find("tr:gt(0)").length;
    if (tablerow < 10) {
        for (var i = tablerow; i < 10; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");
            tr.append("<td id=''></td>");

            $("#searchresult").append(tr);
        }
    }

}
```

`success ajax response`

```
success: function(data) {
    var tr;
    $("#searchresult").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr class="paginate"/>');
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].sid + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id1 + "'>" + data[i].name1 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id2 + "'>" + data[i].name2 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id3 + "'>" + data[i].name3 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id4 + "'>" + data[i].name4 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"searchresult\"  href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");
        $("#searchresult").append(tr);
    }
    updateItems();
},
```

I am doing this [pagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/). I want to make it in a way that the table has always 10 row no matter what. For example the item count is 26 page 1 and page 2 are ok because they both have 10 items but page 3 will have 6 items only. I want to append 4 blank items to page 3 in order to make it 10 items.

What I tried is to append row depending on table row count. But I cant get the current row count for the page the item length I always get is total items which is 26.

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Change `data.length` to `10`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao if i get more than 10 it will not append it on the table?i need to append all data so i need `data.length`..

Comment: You only want 10 items to be appended at any cost right?

Comment: no not 10 items only i mean 10 items per page sorry if you didnt understand my statement. I put a scenario so that it will be easy to understand @GuruprasadRao

Comment: I hope then Travis's answer addresses it right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it will not solve the problem... I will write again the scenario. Example i have 26 items. I will append them to table. Then paginate 10 items per page. Problem arises for 6 remaining items I want to add 4 to those 6 items to make them 10

Comment: The first version was a little too basic, the edited version will accommodate the 26 item issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success function, seed empty results there as blanks. To make sure that even sets of 10 are added, mod the length by 10 and add until that is 0 (or divisible by 10)

```
success: function(data) {

    //insert blanks to fill in blank spaces up to an even multiple of 10
    while(data.length % 10 != 0) data.push({ 
        sid: "", id1: "", name1: "", id2: "", name2: "", 
        id3: "", name3: "", id4: "", name4: ""
    });

    var tr;
    $("#searchresult").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr class="paginate"/>');
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].sid + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id1 + "'>" + data[i].name1 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id2 + "'>" + data[i].name2 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id3 + "'>" + data[i].name3 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td ><span id='" + data[i].id4 + "'>" + data[i].name4 + "</span></td>");
        tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"searchresult\"  href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");
        $("#searchresult").append(tr);
    }
    updateItems();
},
```

Comment: Sir sorry if you didnt understand my problem. My problem is for example I have 26 items. It will be append to table. Then paginated. 10 items each page. Now the problem is for the remaining 6 items. When it is appended to the table it is only 6 rows i want to add 4 rows to that so that it will be 10 rows total.

Comment: @Pekka - I did, but then I trivially missed it in the while loop in the first post. Please see the updated revision.

Comment: Wow and i added my code on the pagination. Works perfectly